# Android Studio: Nothing happens when I try to create a new empty activity

Tags: android-studio

What I am doing:

Right click java > new > activity > empty activity

naming it LoginActivity

gradle builds and finishes but nothing loads and there is not new activity created

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Are you trying to run your app on an emulator or a real device?

Comment: What kind of question is that? It is self explanatory. I expect a new empty activity to be created.

Comment: creating an activity simply adds a new activity to your project. you need to launch the activity somewhere for it to be launched.. you can read about it here: 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity

Comment: That it starting/launching the activity. What I was referring to was the loadout. The .java and .xml files were not built in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED NOW:

USING ANDROID 4.0 FYI

commented out the google() in build.gradle (Project:)
re-synced the project with the gradle files
now able to create new empty activity
need to uncomment out the google() whenever not creating a new activity as the gradle will fail to build otherwise.